# Pandas Replace NaN or Blank values with Previous Value for Matching Row

Tags: pandas, dataframe, iteration

My Data is as follows:

```
Name    Group
Jess    1
Jess    
John    2
John    2
Jeff    2
Jeff    
Fred    3
Fred    3
Fred    
Henry   2
Henry   2
```

I'm trying to find all rows where the person has a blank group, and then replace that blank value with a value if found in the table already for that individual.

My plan was to find all the blank values.

```
df[(pd.isna(df['Group']))]
```

Then write for loop to search the full dataframe for the value for that person and then replace the blank value with that value.

```
for name in df_blank['Name'].unique():    
    df2 = df[(pd.notna(df['Group']) & df['Name']==name)]['Group'].unique()
    df_blank['Group'] == df2['Group'].value
```

However I'm sure this is not the most efficient method. Could anyone help with a more efficient way of doing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `groupby().transform('first')` which works for `NaN` values only:

```
df['Group'] = df.groupby('Name')['Group'].transform('first')
```

To work with both `NaN` and blank strings, we can replace before transform:

```
df['Group'] = (df['Group'].replace('', np.NaN)
                  .groupby(df['Name'])
                  .tranform('first')
              )
```